# "Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode" error in IE11 when exporting text values to .csv, Chrome browser is working fine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

"Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode" error in IE11 when exporting text values to .csv, Chrome browser is working fine with same code.

Below is my code:

```
    define('mybiz.framework.csvsave',
         ['jquery', 'mybiz.framework.loggingservice', 'saveAs'], function ($,
         JL,    saveAs) {  
         'use strict';
         var logger = JL('mybiz.framework.csvsave');
         var generate = function (doc) {
         logger.info("about to save CSV document");
         var startTime = new Date();
         try {
         var textEncoder = new TextEncoder('utf-16le');
         var csvContentEncoded = textEncoder.encode([doc]);
         var bom = new Uint8Array([0xFF, 0xFE]);
         var out = new Uint8Array(bom.byteLength            +csvContentEncoded.byteLength);     
            out.set(bom, 0);
            out.set(csvContentEncoded, bom.byteLength);

            var csvBlob = new Blob([out], {type: 'text/csv'});
            saveAs(csvBlob, "los.csv");
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error("Error generating CSV: " + e.message + "\n" + e.stack);
        }
        var stopTime = new Date();
        logger.info("CSV generation completed in: " + (stopTime - startTime) + "ms");
    };
    return {
        generate: generate
    };
});
```

This below code is calling above function:

```
    self.saveExportCSV = function (data, event) {
                var columns = getColumnsToExport(self.columnsForExport());
                self.exportCSV({'columns': columns, 'generator':   
csvsave.generate, event: event});
            };
```

Comment: i have found using "using strict" in script will throw some errors, but i cant able to find which part of the code is throwing error

Comment: what read only property are you rewriting? `use strict` is working as expected, if you remove the line `use strict;` should work too. But your problem dont have enough information

Comment: i am not sure which property is rewriting but the "doc" seems to be one

Comment: I'm sure IE11 error messages indicate which line of code causes the error - surely that can be useful information in determining which line of code causes the error

Comment: @JaromandaX found the error : "'TextEncoder' is undefined". Not sure why this is causing error . Have to search in Google

Comment: what an odd error to get - surely the error would be `'TextEncoder' is undefined`